# Why does my gas furnace sometimes fail to start, but thermostat believes it is on?

Tags: wiring, furnace, central-heating

I have a Bryant 394CAZ036100 natural gas furnace that operates normally **part** of the time.  But at other times, though the thermostat thinks the heat is on, the furnace has failed to turn on and the house gets colder and colder.

When that happens, we can get it to start again by turning the thermostat to *Off* mode, and then setting it back to *Heat* mode.

The professionals have come to work on this several times, and have yet to figure it out.  (These folks are a well-regarded local firm in Chicago with many decades of experience). Recently, they replaced the original control board with an OEM substitute (using P/N HH84AA020 I believe), and also replaced the thermostat.  And yet the problem persists.

The problem is similar to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62900/why-do-i-have-to-start-my-furnace-manually-every-morning), so perhaps there is faulty wiring, or a faulty sensor or something.  But I would have thought a temperature-related loose solder joint would then make it hard for our furnace to start again once the house is cold. That's not really what we observe -- the misbehavior is at most loosely correlated with house temperature.

I *assume* the pros would have checked out the obvious stuff.  What should I / they be looking for next?  Do any particular sensors or wires arouse suspicion at this point?

Comment: Sounds like bad wiring.  Thermostat is just a switch if it is calling for heat it is connecting the two wires.  Sounds like your hvac company is just throwing parts at the problem.  Intermittent problems are hard though and by the time they come out multiple times you'd already have paid for the part so probably not a bad strategy if the board/thermostat are old anyway.

Comment: if the thermostat says on, you'd just go to the furnace and read the thermostat leads to see if you have 24v ( if you have 24v then the problem is something at the furnace, if you don't it is the thermostat or thermostat wiring or transformer ).

Comment: Thermostats know they are calling for heat. They have no idea if the heat source is responding to that call, they just call for it, and if it never gets warm they keep calling for it, basically.  Off and on again may be clearing some fault at the furnace, or it may indeed be bad wiring with an intermittent connection.

Comment: The big thing is to catch it when it happens. The problem is, that's hard to do. You set it for 72. Temp goes to 70, it turns on and heats to 73 and turns off. Gets down to 70 again, furnace *starts* to turn on but fails - CO2 sensor? flame sensor? some overload somewhere somehow? and stops trying. But you don't notice until an hour later when its dropped to 68. I have a similar very infrequent (average once every few weeks, but not "clockwork") problem where I have ruled out the thermostat but still haven't solved the problem. Very hard to do unless you catch it right when it happens.